# how to set a server based swf clock that follows host servers time

Tags: time, webserver, flash

I host an SWF clock on my server, the problem is I can't set it to follow the host servers time, instead it follows the clock on my pc, is there a way for me to make the clock follow the server time?

[this is the link for the clock](https://secure.telexperience.co/5005-orange.swf?TimeZone=MST&)

Answer (score 0):

SWF is executed on the client so if the clock calls a method that determines the current time it is gonna be the time on the client. That said, it is of course possible to build a clock which follows the server time. For that, a service on the server needs to provide the current time information and send it to the client.

A related idea is adjusting the time found on the client with that on the server only once and then displaying client time + adjustment, see for instance [Get the difference between a server side time and client side time and display it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7287539/get-the-difference-between-a-server-side-time-and-client-side-time-and-display-i?lq=1)