# How to synchronise a client webpage timer with the server

Tags: javascript, ajax, time, synchronization, client-side

What is the best way to synchronise the time on a webpage with the server?

My webpage needs to start a countdown at the same time for all users, and and end at exactly the same time to prevent any one user having a slight time advantage.

My problem is similar to this question but the accepted answer helps but does not fully answer my concerns:  [how-to-sync-a-javascript-countdown-with-server-time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5357719/how-to-sync-a-javascript-countdown-with-server-time)

I use Ajax after pageload to get the server time, but am I guaranteed over 15 minutes that the countdown will end at exactly the same time for each client?

Even if the timers accurately measure the time, there could still be a discrepancy of just under 1 second between client pages caused by disregarding the milliseconds for the setInterval - is there any way to overcome this?

Comment: Can you give a bit more information about what this is for? You can never trust the client so you will have to check this on the server side anyway.

Comment: @TheShellfishMeme, the logic of the page is like an auction. I have the validation in PHP on the server, but I want to prevent a client being able to submit and then it being blocked by the server - it can just lead to disputes with the client saying they did enter in time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In modern browsers, you can achieve this by assigning a timestamp to a JavaScript variable, and use the [`Performance` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Navigation_timing) to calculate the exact time.

Example:

```
var tsp = new Date('Sun Feb 19 2012 17:55:14 GMT+0100 (CET)'); // "Timestamp"

window.onload = function() {
    var performance = window.performance || window.mozPerformance || window.msPerformance || window.webkitPerformance || {};
    tsp.setTime(tsp.getTime() + performance.timing.loadEventStart - performance.timing.navigationStart
    // after window.onload, you're sync with the server

    // Example of timer:
    setInterval(function() {
        tsp.setSeconds(tsp.getSeconds() + 1);
        document.title = tsp.toString();
    }, 1000); // 1000 ms = timer may be off by 500ms.
};
```

For more information on this object, have a look at the [MDN's article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Navigation_timing).
A demo is provided [here](http://webtimingdemo.appspot.com/).

Answer (score 11):

The accepted answer is good and helped inspire me as I wrote a library to solve this problem.  The library yields more precise answers by looking at the load times of itself, rather than the whole page (as done with performance.timing above) and then gets even better precision by following with a series of 10 XMLHttpRequests.  Also, addressing your second concern, my library doesn't disregard the milliseconds (as does the accepted answer).

The library is called [ServerDate](https://github.com/BallBearing/ServerDate) and is freely available.

Here's part of the README:

You can use `ServerDate` as you would use the `Date` function or one of its
instances, e.g.:

```
> ServerDate()
"Mon Aug 13 2012 20:26:34 GMT-0300 (ART)"

> ServerDate.now()
1344900478753

> ServerDate.getMilliseconds()
22
```

There is also a new method to get the precision of ServerDate's estimate of the
server's clock (in milliseconds):

```
> ServerDate.toLocaleString() + " ± " + ServerDate.getPrecision() + " ms"
"Tue Aug 14 01:01:49 2012 ± 108 ms"
```

You can see the difference between the server's clock and the browsers clock, in milliseconds:

```
> ServerDate - new Date()
39
```

Answer (score 2):

Ideally your solution would involve the server sending out the signal that the submit form is open to all clients at the same time. For that you could use [web sockets](http://dev.w3.org/html5/websockets/) if you have no problem with excluding people with older browsers. There are also fallbacks using long polling for those browsers.

I am not sure how well websockets do together with PHP though.

I've only ever used [socket.io](http://socket.io/) together with node JS. With that solution it would be trivial to set a server-side timeout and notify all clients at the same time when it's complete. It automatically detects the browser support and chooses a method that works best for a given browser.

Using this solution the clients will only ever allow submissions when the server has told them it is ready. As long as the server you submit to performs validation you should be fine.