# what is the fastest way to get server time in JavaScript from a web browser?

Tags: javascript, ajax, http, client-server, clock-synchronization

in fact, i wanna synchronize client-side time with server time, [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638337/the-best-way-to-synchronize-client-side-javascript-clock-with-server-date) is really good, but there are any other ideas faster? in other words, can we find a faster way to get server time in JavaScript from a web browser?

Answer (score 0):

Sway - the link you mentioned is the better way to go, i dont think you can anyway sync with server clock without knowing what is the time on the server.

in the below example he has given a good pictorial representation too.

http://codemadesimple.wordpress.com/2012/06/18/timesync-with-asp-net-mvc-4/