# node.js timezone independent Date.now()

Tags: javascript, node.js

What is a common way to sync timeStamps across servers and clients in node.js, not dependent on timezone?

e.g., a Date.now() equivalent that would provide the same time on the server and client.
Preferably without any node.js modules, or client side libraries.

Comment: This thread may be of interest: [The best way to synchronize client-side javascript clock with server date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638337/the-best-way-to-synchronize-client-side-javascript-clock-with-server-date)

Comment: @dc5 I ended up using something similar to that thread, but I greatly simplified it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

JavaScript timestamps are always based in [UTC](http://es5.github.io/#x15.9.1.1):

> Time is measured in ECMAScript in milliseconds since 01 January, 1970 UTC.

Date strings from different timezones can have the same timestamp.

```
var a = "2013-08-26 12:00 GMT-0800";
var b = "2013-08-27 00:00 GMT+0400";

console.log(Date.parse(a) === Date.parse(b)); // true
console.log(Date.parse(a)); // 1377547200000
console.log(Date.parse(b)); // 1377547200000
```

And, [`Date.now()`](http://es5.github.io/#x15.9.4.4) should return relatively similar values across systems.