# JS Date() returns correct timezone but wrong date

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, timezone

I am experiencing weird behaviour when trying to get current date using Date() in javascript.
First, I set the timezone to Cuba by

```
sudo ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/Cuba /etc/localtime
```

and ran `Date()` in another console running node.js. This was the output -

```
> Date()
'Thu Oct 31 2013 06:28:25 GMT+1100 (CDT)'
```

On changing the timezone,

```
sudo ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Vladivostok /etc/localtime
```

and running `Date()` again, this is the output -

```
> Date()
'Thu Oct 31 2013 06:28:31 GMT+1100 (VLAT)'
```

Can anyone please explain why does this happen and how can I get the time based on timezone ?

Comment: What does `date` say when you run it in the shell after making this change? (I mean /usr/bin/date, not node.js shell)

Comment: Check this link, here it help [SO - Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18450851/node-js-timezone-independant-date-now)

Comment: @ithcy, Here's what it says -
`[parin@arch ~]$ date
Thu Oct 31 06:39:59 VLAT 2013
[parin@arch ~]$ date
Wed Oct 30 15:40:06 CDT 2013`

Comment: Did you exit node.js and reenter after changing the time zone?  Did you try `new Date()` instead of just `Date()`?

Comment: Also, I believe the correct tz for Cuba is `America/Havana`.

Comment: @MattJohnson, I tried `new Date()` and it gives UTC time, but shows the correct timezone -
`> new Date()
Wed Oct 30 2013 20:09:27 GMT+0000 (VLAT)
> new Date()
Wed Oct 30 2013 20:09:48 GMT+0000 (CDT)`  and I just selected Cuba arbitrarily so that I can get different dates till the next few hours. But thanks for pointing out the correct tz for it.

Answer (score 2):

Some messing around with OS timezones and `node` reveals that, while `node` correctly picks up **timezone** changes while it is running, it fails to update the **offset**.  This is why both of the dates show `GMT+1100`.

If you restart node, you'll find that both the offset and the timezone are correct.  I suspect that this is intentional to avoid the time changing unexpectedly during a run, but can't find anything to that effect with a Google search.

Comment: yes on restarting node, it shows the correct date. But, I want to show the date change on timezone change in a JS script. I am just using `node` shell to check this.
Is there a way to calculate the offset from the timezone ?

Comment: @ParinPorecha You're expecting the timezone to change during the run of a script?

Comment: Yes. I think I should better explain it - The script is a gnome-shell extension and it displays a clock. So, if the user changes the time/timezone, I want the clock to get updated right away without the need of restarting gnome-shell or the computer.

Comment: Most JavaScript runtimes won't pick up time zone changes until they are restarted.  It's interesting that Node picks up the change in name at all.  The only environment I know of that doesn't require a restart is Microsoft Internet Explorer.  All other browsers and interpreters require a restart after a time zone change.