# Is it possible to change the JavaScript client side clock?

Tags: javascript, client-server, client

**My problem:**

The web application that I am building is very dependant on that the client and server side clocks are in pretty good sync.

To calculate the offset between the client and server time clock is not a problem, [it has very elaborate answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638337/the-best-way-to-synchronize-client-side-javascript-clock-with-server-date).

**My question is:**

Is it possible to alter the default clock from JavaScript which `Date` etc is based on? Or is my best shot to build an extension of the `Date` class or similar?

Comment: As far as I know, the JS clock returns the system's date / time. You can't change that.

Comment: Kind of hope that there is some magic offset function or something that processes the time between the system and f.x. Date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[moment.js](http://momentjs.com) has a very powerful date api on top of javascript's Date object.

You could look for a plugin (or quite easily build your own) that takes into account some kind of custom 'timezone'. Thus shifting your date-related calculations to any value needed.