# How to get server date using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using AngularJS client-side application and working with date and time. My problem is that local system date anyone can change, to protect this I want to use server date without any get or post request. Is there any way to get server date using JavaScript?

Comment: Wait. JavaScript is client-side language. You will need to "ask" server-side to fetch its time. Note that connection & loading time may affect the accuracy of time obtained

Comment: you will need additional ajax request

Comment: yeah.... loading may affect the accuracy of the time....with ajax post req is it possible?

Comment: Bear in mind that even if you successfully get the date from the server, a malicious client could still change it. If an accurate date is system-critical you will have to validate on the server side.

Comment: *'to protect this I want to use server date without any get or post request"* hah, what?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)

Comment: Either you write a timestamp when the page is rendered and adjust the user's time or you make a request and fetch the timestamp with an Ajax call.

Answer (score 5):

If you are running JavaScript at the **client-side**, the only way to find the **server** time is *asking* the server what is the *current* time. There is no magic here. You need to make a request to the server.

Options:

1. Use [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started) or [Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API).
2. If the HTML page is rendered in the server, you can write the current time during the page render and send it to client.

Please, note that it is not possible to have a **precise** time of the server due to network delays, but you can get pretty close using the code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1641147/1476885) (modified):

```
var offset = 0;
function calcOffset() {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "https://stackoverflow.com/", false);
    xmlhttp.send();

    var dateStr = xmlhttp.getResponseHeader('Date');
    var serverTimeMillisGMT = Date.parse(new Date(Date.parse(dateStr)).toUTCString());
    var localMillisUTC = Date.parse(new Date().toUTCString());

    offset = serverTimeMillisGMT -  localMillisUTC;
}

function getServerTime() {
    var date = new Date();

    date.setTime(date.getTime() + offset);

    return date;
}
```

Comment: @epascarello it's just an AJAX call.  jQuery *probably* does this internally with IE.

Comment: Believe it or not, there are still organizations where the architecture gods don't allow jQuery or any other open-source.  * sigh *

Comment: @epascarello, I've updated the answer to remove the old ActiveX reference.

Comment: The OP specifically states "without any get or post request". You were expecting accolades for doing exactly the opposite?