# How to show real-time server date and time on Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, datetime

In Nodejs, how to read the date and time from the server and **display in real time** on my webpage? By using Javascript inside my webpage, it will pick up the date and time of the computer I'm using, not the server. I want the date and time from server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The best way to synchronize client-side javascript clock with server date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638337/the-best-way-to-synchronize-client-side-javascript-clock-with-server-date)

Comment: Hi! thanks for your attention. The way of @kkpoon has solved my problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may simply use [socket.io](https://socket.io/) to do it.

On server side, create a websocket server, publish the date time every interval (depend on your requirement, seconds, minutes, ...)

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('datetime', { datetime: new Date().getTime() });
});
```

On browser side, subscribe the websocket and received the date time from server.

```
var socket = io.connect('http://your-socket-io-server');
socket.on('datetime', function (data) {
  $("#clock").text(new Date(data));
});
```

Comment: It works perfectly. I'd just add in your answer, a practical example of where to find the "socket.io" in the system, instead of `http: // your-socket-io-server`. For me it's OK, but I'm saying this because it might be useful for other people. Thank you !!

Comment: I find it a little unclear where to be adding these code snippets

Comment: I followed this tutorial that aim to do the same thing: https://dev.to/suhakim/create-a-real-time-digital-clock-with-node-and-socketio-53dm