# How does UTC work with Javascript and computers with wrong times?

Tags: javascript, time, utc, systemtime

I have been writing some JavaScript code that relies upon universal time. I have been doing this online with two computers. One of which is 24 minutes behind the other.

Example:

```
Computer 1: 25/07/2020, 21:57     Computer 2: 25/07/2020, 22:21
```

When both computers enter a UTC number they are still the equivalent of 24 minutes apart.

```
Computer 1: 1595710054892    Computer 2: 1595711497605
```

This difference in time is causing problems with my programme as it relies upon timed notifications.

Is there anyway to correct for this or will I just have to hope that computers that use my JavaScript code will all have the same time within their respective timezone?

Comment: If the notifications go to or from a server, could your JavaScript code then also get the correct time from that server?

Comment: There are also some answers [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638337/the-best-way-to-synchronize-client-side-javascript-clock-with-server-date) that might be helpful. It's a bit dated (no pun intended), but has some good tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't trust the clock on the computer (which is, frankly, shocking for a network-connected system in 2020) then you need to get the current time from somewhere else.

The standard way to do this would be to use the [Network Time Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol).

A quick Google turns up [this JavaScript implementation of an NTP client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ntp-client):

> ```
> var ntpClient = require('ntp-client');
>  
> ntpClient.getNetworkTime("pool.ntp.org", 123, function(err, date) {
>     if(err) {
>         console.error(err);
>         return;
>     }
>  
>     console.log("Current time : ");
>     console.log(date); // Mon Jul 08 2013 21:31:31 GMT+0200 (Paris, Madrid (heure d’été))
> });
> ```

If you're dealing with JS in a browser, you won't be able to use the NTP protocol directly so you would need to proxy the request via some server-side code which would lose some accuracy (but assuming a reasonable network connection, that would be in the order of a few seconds rather than 10s of minutes).